# How to switchcases inside if loop

Tags: java

I'm stuck at a question that requests me if the user insert something else instead "e" "x" nums between 1 to 10, then it's returning "incorrect"

here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            int Num = 0;
            Num = sc.nextInt();
            String str = sc.nextLine();

            switch (Num) { 
            case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
            case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8:
            case 9: case 10:
                System.out.println("this is a volume");
                break;
            case : if((Num>10)||(Num <0))
                System.out.println("this is incorrect");
                break;
            }
            switch (str) {
            case "e": case "E":
                System.out.println("Shutting Down");
                break;
            case "x" : case "X":
                System.out.println("Mute");
                break;
            case "a":case "b":case "c":case "d":case "f":case "g":case "h":case "i":case "j":
            case "k":case "l":case "m":case "n":case "o":case "p":case "q":case "r":case "s":
            case "t":case "u":case "v":case "w":case "y":case "z":
                System.out.println("this is incorrect");
                break;
            default:
                break;

        } 
        }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("stopped");
    }

}
```

}

thank you

Comment: We can't compare String with `==` String has it's **equals()** method.

Comment: I think you're confused about what a switch does - you define `case 1` for `Num` as a check for `Num > 10 || Num < 1`. I don't really know what you're trying to do but that if-statement will always be false; if `Num` is 1, we know for a fact that it is neither greater than 10 or less than 1.

Comment: What is your user suppose to insert first? is it Text or Number?

Comment: I wonder how people come up with stuff like "if loop". Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, as you did not specify how many time the user should enter the input. However, you can have a look at this example, take the idea of the approach and then create your own one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert E for Shutdown, X for Mute and Numbers between 1 to 10 for Volume");
        String input = in.nextLine().trim(); // read the entire line after removing spaces if any, then parse it

        if(input.length()>0){ // that means the user entered something
            try{
                int volumeValue = Integer.parseInt(input); // if it's not a number, it will throw exception that will be handled in the catch block
                if(volumeValue>=1 && volumeValue<=10){// then evaluate the value
                    System.out.println("This is a Volume");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Volume Value");
                }
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){ // if you reach this block that means it's not a number
                if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){ // to accept both uppercase and lowercase
                    System.out.println("Shutting Down");
                }
                else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("x")){ 
                    System.out.println("Mute");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Input");
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You have NOT entered anything!");
        }
    }

}
```

**Test**

```
Insert E for Shutdown, X for Mute and Numbers between 1 to 10 for Volume
e   -> Shutting Down
x   -> Mute 
5   -> This is a Volume
12  -> Incorrect Volume Value
ZzZ -> Incorrect Input
    -> You have NOT entered anything!
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
switch (Num)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
                System.out.println("this is a volume");
                break;
            default:
            {
                if ((Num > 10) || (Num < 0))
                {
                    System.out.println("this is incorrect");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer! OP did not ask for numbers only, added to that your approach is not very good!

Comment: @Yahya , there is no way as per my knowledge to add if in switch case. I feel that my solution will work

Comment: this went well but what's with the strings :\

Comment: @NepalEmilyAsserat as per your program, if the given string does not fall in A to Z it will go to default case where you can print as incorrect